# JOptionPane how to stop it closing when I hit "Ok"

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

By default, JOptionPane closes the frame when I select any button but in my case, I want it to stay open on when I select one of the buttons so I can show a pop up screen (with the original frame in the background).

How would I do that??

Here is my code: 
(its very messy, i'm just gathering my thoughts. I have a more official program which is much larger and i will implement this in later)

When I select A-E, I will pop up a dialog with "Pick" or "Cancel". I don't want the original frame to close though.

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Quiz
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String message = "";
        for(int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
            message += "hello world ";

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new JLabel(message));
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,400));
        Object test = scrollPane;


        String[] possibleAns = { "E", "D", "C", "B", "A" };   

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(message);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setMargin(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
        scrollPane.getViewport().setView(textArea);
        test = scrollPane;

        int rc = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, test, "Advanced Quiz   Program",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, 0, null, possibleAns, possibleAns[0]);





        System.out.println(rc);

        String[] pick = {"Pick", "Close" }; 
        switch(rc)
        {
            case 4: 
                    System.out.println("You picked A");
                    JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(new JLabel(message));
                    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,400));
                    Object messaseA = scrollPane;





                    JTextArea textArea2 = new JTextArea("blah blah");
                    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
                    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                    textArea.setMargin(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
                    scrollPane.getViewport().setView(textArea);
                    test = scrollPane;
                    int retVal = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, test, "Advanced Quiz Program",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, 0, null, pick, pick[0]);
                     break;
            case 3:
                            System.out.println("You picked B");
                            break;
            case 2:
                            System.out.println("You picked C");
                            break;
            case 1:
                            System.out.println("You picked D");
                            break;
            case 0:
                            System.out.println("You picked E");
                            break;
            default:
                            System.out.println("error");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but your main frame is closing when you choose one of the JOptionPane buttons because your `main` method is terminating.

Answer (score 3):

Best bet: don't use a JOptionPane. If you want a top level main window, use a JFrame, if you want a dialog window that stays open but is non-modal, then use a non-modal JDialog. If you want a modal dialog window then use a JOptionPane or a modal JDialog (which a JOptionPane is actually created from).

If you must use a JOptionPane, you can create one with a JOptionPane constructor extract the dialog from it, and make it non-modal.

---

Based on your edit and your code it does seem that you're trying to use a JOptionPane as a main program window, something that you really don't want to do. Let me suggest that:

- First and foremost, get most everything out of the main method. That method should be used for creating your initial objects, here your GUI, and setting it in motion.
- And then make classes that create POJO's -- plain old Java objects, objects with constructors, instance fields/properties, and instance methods.
- One of your classes should create a GUI, likely a JFrame or main application window, that holds your JTextArea and however many buttons you need.
- That you only use JOptionPanes when one of the button has been pressed, an ActionListener attached to the button will do whatever actions are needed, including perhaps launching a JOptionPane with "Pick" or "Cancel" options.